# Android Studio will not run emulators - error 0x501

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, android-virtual-device

I am trying to run Android virtual devices in Android Studio.  I'm on Windows 7 Ultimate SP 1. Dell laptop with Intel Core 2 Duo T7700 2.4 GHz, 4 GB RAM. No matter what I try, I get something like the following:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_22_x86
Creating filesystem with parameters:
Size: 69206016
Block size: 4096
Blocks per group: 32768
Inodes per group: 4224
Inode size: 256
Journal blocks: 1024
Label: 
Blocks: 16896
Block groups: 1
Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
emulator: device fd:576
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
creating window 51 69 385 683
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
distrib/android-emugl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glAttachShader:177 error 0x501
distrib/android-emugl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glAttachShader:177 error 0x501
distrib/android-emugl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glDetachShader:599 error 0x501
distrib/android-emugl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glDetachShader:599 error 0x501
```

Sorry, I know there are similar questions on Stack Exchange but they're unanswered.

Comment: Can you show the specs of an emulator you're trying to run? Maybe one of your options is causing it (Nexus_5_API_22_x86 in your case).

Comment: it may be because of the GPU emulation setting. What is your setting for emulate GPU?

Comment: That was it! I unchecked the "Use Host GPU" box in Virtual Device Configuration and it worked, albeit very slowly. Thank you!

Comment: I was hoping to see a solution for the problem (cannot run hardware accelerated emulator), and not just avoiding it..